# Saga or RSAGA wind.shelter

Tags: saga

I would like to run the Saga wind shelter index (wind.shelter). It was apparently on older versions of Saga and has been re-added to Saga 7.4 and 7.5

Here is what I have done:

1. Installed Saga 7.3 and all is well with that;
2. Installed R and RSaga in order to have access to the wind.shelter module; however Rsaga expects versions 2.3.1 LTS - 6.2.0 and I can't get wind-shelter to run in Rsaga;
3. Tried to install version 7.5 of Saga which reintegrates the module, without success.

So I don't know how to proceed. Any thoughts? Is there any way I can run the rsaga version of the wind shelter index from within saga_gui?

Please note that I am running Ubuntu 19.10.